# Create txt file on Linux as super user with Java

Tags: java, linux

I am new to java and Linux. I have to create a local file on Linux with Java code. But it does not allow me to create the file only if I am running as super user.

In terminal, if I run "vi test.text", it does not allow me to writer to the file. So need to run as super user "sudo vi test.text" to create the file.

How to write the Java code to run as super user to create the file?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to write your file? In many cases there is a very good reason that only the super-user has writing access! If you are writing an installer, refuse to run if you don't have the neccessary priveleges (if uid != 0). Per-user files, e.g. configuration files, belong into their respective /home folders.

Answer (score 2):

Write a java application to create a file and run the jar using sudo.

```
sudo java -jar filecreater.jar
```

The user as which you are running the java app should have write permission in the folder you are trying to create the file.

Comment: good answer. The jar could detect if it was run as super-user; if not, try to restart itself using `sudo`. The user should then be automatically prompted for the password.