# Java code accessing root folder getting access denied error

Tags: java

I am trying to create a text file in a root folder on a Linux system (Ubuntu) using Java. My problem is that I get an access denied message. My user is normal user so I am trying to create the file with root user but I am stuck here.

Here's my code :

```
package --------.com;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CreateFileDemo
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {    
      try {
         File file = new File("/root/newfile.txt");

             boolean fvar = file.createNewFile();
         if (fvar){
              System.out.println("File has been created successfully");
         }
         else{
              System.out.println("File already present at the specified location");
         }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occurred:");
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you assume that a normal user is allowed to write to /root folder?

Comment: This may help you [Create txt file on Linux as super user with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528175/create-txt-file-on-linux-as-super-user-with-java).

Comment: either change target location with in user directory or execute  java program as sudo user .. `sudo java <mainClass>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start by understanding Linux file system permissions: 
Typically:

- the root folder / belongs **root** (surprise), not individual users.
- individual users do **not** have the right to create or modify files directly under /.

So, first of all, your *idea* to have a normal user create files under / is simply: wrong. You are not supposed to open that locked door.

Now, to still be able to do that:

- run the whole JVM with sudo (as root process): obviously that opens a whole can of security related worms. So: don't do that. Because anything that happens in that JVM is done with `root` authority.
- alternatively: instead of using java APIs to create that file, you *could* run a system command such as `sudo touch /root/newfile.txt`, and then use something like [sudoers](https://www.linux.com/blog/configuring-linux-sudoers-file) to avoid being asked for a password.

In other words: you either have to run the whole JVM as root process (discouraged), or you have to make a system call with "root" rights.

Answer (score 0):

Just use $chmod 777 file_name.txt